How to set/choose SSO for user when multiple SSO configurations exist on the org
My goal is to have 2 SSO configurations active on my org. For each internal user I would like to based on criteria or a link direct them to the SSO they should be using. In a way, bind the SSO config to the user.
Is there a way to have a separate login url or other identifier so that I can still have both login methods available but users are being sent to only 1?
EDIT:
If possible, I would like to keep this as configuration as much as I can. Is there not a method to give each SSO configuration its own URL so that I could give a direct method to their login rather than sending them to the generic login form to have them choose?
I am following the Identity Provider-Initiated SAML Flow from this help article. I need to be able to do this with two separate apps on the same salesforce org while directing the user to the correct IDP.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.identity_provider_about.htm&type=5
For some reason my configuration provided the same login URL (myTestdomain.my.salesforce.com) for both Single Sign On configurations. How did this screenshot get the /so=00D....


Login Discovery: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_login_discovery.htm&type=5

I think this would work but I was hoping for "clicks not code". Is there not a method where I could maybe pick a different entity id or something so that each IDP would have its own login URL. From there couldn't I direct users to that URL so we would know which one they needed?

If the identity provider (IdP) supports IdP-initiated flow, the URLs you want could be provided by the IdP.

This is some new search terms to try to find. I will look that up and let you know if this is what I needed.

Thanks @identigral I found my answer after figuring out the difference between Identity provider initiated vs Service provider initiated flows.


The issue was on the Identity Providers configuration which in this case was Microsoft. When they removed the value for "Sign on URL", users who would access Salesforce through Microsoft would no longer be prompted for which identity provider to use.
The reason for this is the Sign On URL configuration value forces the application to use a "Service Provider Initiated" Flow rather than an "Identity Initiated Flow". Identity Initiated flow is needed in order to direct a user into Salesforce directly without having to pick with Identity provider to use (setup through My Domain login method)
Salesforce provides Enterprise Microsoft Entra Applications for both Sandboxes and Production orgs. The Sandbox installation supports Identity Provider Initiated  and Service Provider Initiated while the production one only supports Service Provider Initiated. This means you have to create a custom Microsoft App in order to allow the Sign On URL to be optional.
Resource I found my information: Microsoft Board
